# EWS failes with Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, ssl, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to fetch free / busy using EWS 
Ive installed the latest nuget package Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices

I'm also setting everything I know of to ignore cert. errors:

```
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 |  SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

The code I'm using to fetch appointments:

```
 //Set up the service with correct credentials.
var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1)
{
    Credentials = new WebCredentials(Account, Password, Domain), 
    TraceEnabled = true, 
    EnableScpLookup = false
};
service.Url = new Uri(ServiceUrl);

// Create a list of attendees.
var attendees = Contacts.Select(contact => new AttendeeInfo { SmtpAddress = contact.Email, AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Required }).ToList();

// Specify availability options.
var myOptions = new AvailabilityOptions
                {
                    MeetingDuration = 30, 
                    RequestedFreeBusyView = FreeBusyViewType.DetailedMerged,
                    DetailedSuggestionsWindow = new TimeWindow(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(Days))

                };

// Return a set of free/busy times.
var freeBusyResults = service.GetUserAvailability(attendees, new TimeWindow(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(Days)),AvailabilityData.FreeBusyAndSuggestions, myOptions);
```

This code works for 5 out of 6 exchange servers I have, but one of them gives "The request failed. The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." error message.

If I set up fiddler to act as an proxy for the call, and tell fiddler to decrypt, everything works.

I just want to ignore ALL ssl errors and get the data, how do I do that?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: No, this is still not working

Answer (score 0):

The Managed API is just using HTTPWebRequest as the underlying class to do the Request/response. If it works with fiddler mostly likely your problem is environmental/Client related. I would suggest you enable tracing https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dgorti/2005/09/18/using-system-net-tracing/ you should then be able to see what happens at the lower level when it fails.